# conditional formatting of a cell when a cell name is used on a formula inside that cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a cell when it contains an equation with reference to a named cell.

Example: Cell I71 contains the following equation. =G71*Admin_Labor_Rate

Admin_Labor_Rate has a value of $50, and is the name of cell B152.

Now I want to find all cells that reference cell B152 "Admin_Labor_Rate" and apply conditional formatting (highlight). I have two other Labor Rates, so I want to use cell highlighting to distinctly identify if the labor is being performed by technicians, admin, or engineering.

I have done a lot of research and tried a lot of methods, but it seems as close as I can get is if the cell equates to a certain value, then I can format it.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts the community may have on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula with conditional formatting:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Admin_Labor_Rate", FORMULATEXT(A1)))
```

Where `A1` is the top-left cell of the range you want to conditionally format. For example, you select range `F20:H30` and enter the formula with `F20` instead of `A1`.

Comment: Might want to mention that FORMULATEXT was introduced with [tag:excel-2016] and I'm not sure if that is the standard version or Office 365/Tablet version only (I think the former).

Comment: @Jeeped good mention. But it's actually  2013 (whicn I'm using atm).

Comment: You're right of course; I went to [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) but didn't notice the [tag:excel-2013].

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, and fortunately I am using excel-2013.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a User Defined Function (i.e. UDF).

```
function formulaContains(rng as range, nr as string) as boolean
    formulaContains= rng.hasformula and cbool(instr(1, rng.formula, nr, vbtextcompare))
end function
```